# Is it possible to grant a profile to all the fields of one SObject?

Tags: profile, field-level-security

We have created a new SObject with like 100 fields and create a new custom profile.

When we deploy to production we can't deploy the new profile. So we have created one in prod and do the field level security. The pain part is we are going through every new field to set the field level security.

Is there a way to grant access for the new profile every field's access for this new SObject?

I can think of permission set. But it seems to me permission set can be only applied to users, not a profile.

Comment: There's some handy Chrome extensions (like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-admin-check-al/efcahpjiijlbojmfmaceicchnhkgdkje)) that make this setup process hurt a lot less.

Comment: @DavidReed It'd be useful if it was a more full-featured extension. Luckily, this is one of those things you can do in a Bookmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have a bookmark you can use that I created some years ago. Note that I've only tested it in Classic, and only in the classic Profile Editor, but you can probably alter it to work in other modes, too. Just go in to your bookmark manager, create a new bookmark, then go in to the edit field level security page for a profile's field access to the object, and activate the bookmark.

```
javascript:var a,b,c,d,e,f;a=document;b=v=>a.querySelectorAll(v);c=v=>a.querySelector(v);d=(j,k)=>[].forEach.call(j,k);e=b('input[type=checkbox]');f=c('select option[value="2"]');if(e)d(e,v=>v.checked=1);if(f)f.selected=1;c('input[name=save]').click();
```

Due to restrictions on SFSE, I can't make a link for you to bookmark. Note that this has to be all on one line. Also, this was only tested on Chrome, so other browsers may or may not work.